# What dependencies needed for AndroidJUnit4.class

Tags: java, android, maven, junit, automated-tests

I am creating a test class to test an Android application and I would like to use the `AndroidJUnit4` class as runner:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
```

However I can't figure out what dependencies do I need to add to my Maven project to get it. I tried these:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.uphyca</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

The last one seemed the most promising but it only added the following classes:

```
AndroidJUnit4TestAdapter
AndroidJUnit38ClassRunner
AndroidJUnit3Builder
```

which is not what I need.

Comment: What error do you get with these?

Comment: @MiserableVariable well it just looks that the `AndroidJUnit4` class is not a part of these projects so Eclipse is just saying that it can't be resolved to a type.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add this directly:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.uphyca</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Or if you are just looking for the dependencies, try  to look this page:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.uphyca/android-junit4/0.5

Comment: Thanks, I forgot top mention but I already tried this one too. I will edit my question.